# Spring Boot Whitelabel Error Page almost everywhere

Tags: spring, maven, jsp, spring-boot

Facing some difficulties trying to run Spring Boot to work with JSP pages. I know the limitations provided in documentation, so made everything according to the rules. However, can't find a problem.

I'll try to provide as much information as possible.

Wanted to start using Spring Boot. I'm using:

IntelliJ IDEA, Maven, Maven Spring Boot Plugin, Embedded Tomcat. [Link](https://github.com/zdiyax/demo11) to the project sample.

The REST controller works fine, but when I try to link jsp to the common controller, I 100% end up with Whitelabel error page, stating 404.

Moving files from `WEB-INF` to `resources/static` doesn't help.

The problem is even when I'm trying to run the simplest quick-start Spring Boot projects, I'm facing exceptions. [Here](https://gist.github.com/zdiyax/eb463b7bbb73a3ea16e8e23b9cf3f9f3)'s exception log when I tried to load the example from mkyong site.

I tried to manage maven dependencies manually, as I browsed through some "potential" solutions and found that it could be jar conflict. I even tried to launch the project on a completely fresh operational system - that's the level of my despair.

**Any guidance will be accepted as a divine ambrosia.**

**UPDATE**

When trying to run the project again using `mvn spring-boot` after adding `javax.servlet-api` in dependencies got the following error. Log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-
maven-plugin:1.4.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project demo: An 
exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: 
Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerExceptio
n: Unable to start embedded Tomcat: Failed to start component 
[StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]: 
Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: A child container 
failed during start -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with 
the -
e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**UPDATE**

Using suggestion of @Piotr Gwiazda, tried the same but with Thymeleaf instead of JSP. Worked. However, I would like to know why JSP did not.

Comment: I'm downvoting because this question seems to be about multiple issues, as the answers seem quite unrelated, this makes the question hard to read and messy for future visitors.

Comment: I am not able to go beyond this error. I am trying simple controller class with few methods but it looks like that is not being resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, your code has two webapp folders. One (wrong location)under **src/** and the other one under (correct)**src/main/**. Now your WEB-INF/jsp whas in the wrong one. So, move it to the appropriate folder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for response. That caused some errors to occur, probably some classes conflict with each other. I attached log to the main post.

Comment: `Wed May 17 00:28:36 ALMT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/jsp/index.jsp`. The output still the same. I'm starting to think the problem is somewhere on mapping level. Controller somehow doesn't want to meet jsp.

Comment: yes, I noticed that. Not a single damn change over there.

Answer (score 1):

you can use one such sample configuration

Create src/main/resources source package and place the static resources in that location.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = { "classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
            "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        //resolver.setPrefix("/resources/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

     @Override
        public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
                DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
        }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Well, it's still a black whitelabel error page, but now instead of displaying intended jsp location like `/src/main/resources/templates/index.jsp`, it shows that there's `No message available`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're trying to use JSP page as template for view rendering for `HelloController`. Means that JSP file should be probably in `src/main/resources/templates`.

Mind that JSPs are not the suggested way for creating views. I'd give [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) or others a chance. [See here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines)

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried to move jsp files pretty much everywhere. Still no reaction. I heard about Thymeleaf, it's primarily suggested by spring.io itself. However, the problem set and it needs to be solved :)

Comment: `src/main/resources/templates` does not either?

Comment: unfortunately, yes.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Thymeleaf. I tried a quick tutorial, entered the command without a single breath done, and it worked! However, I would definitely like to find out what's wrong with JSP version.